# Cannot align the flex card items next to each other after I used jinja 2

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jinja2

I want my page to show group of card elements in a flex-box container. I am using this code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card">
                        {% for object in form.obj_list %}
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/small_book.png" alt="book_icon">
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">{{ object.title }}</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">This book was written by {{ object.author }} in {{ object.p_year }}</p>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here, I am using jinja 2 statements to access the results of the search query for my database. The code IS creating card elements like I want but they are all stacked on top of each other. I used `flex-box` on `row` class, I gave it `flex-wrap` style but they are not working at all. The cards are just staying on top of each other. Does anyone know how to do this or what is the reason behind this?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `card-group` should also be a `row`

Comment: Nope, didnt work

Comment: Try adding div element inside for loop to display them one below the other

Comment: how? I already have a div